# I am tryin edit my app on playstore consol but i am getting the following error

Tags: android, google-play-console

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

## **Manifest Error Message

## **

Merging Errors: Warning application@android:icon was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:32 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present Template.app main manifest (this file), line 31 Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Template.app main manifest (this file), line 56 Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Template.app main manifest (this file), line 92 Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Template.app main manifest (this file), line 98

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.btn.hsn.mwanajamii">

    <!-- Always Required to get content and check if internet is available -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Always Required for image coaching & maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required for notifications & radio -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Required for maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Required for visualizer & radio -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <!-- Required for tumblr -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <!-- Required for in-app purchases -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <!-- Activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".providers.videos.ui.VideoDetailActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            />
        <activity android:name=".providers.wordpress.ui.WordpressDetailActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".comments.CommentsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HolderActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".attachmentviewer.ui.AttachmentActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".attachmentviewer.ui.AudioPlayerActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".attachmentviewer.ui.VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:exported="true"
            android:name=".providers.woocommerce.ui.CheckoutActivity"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />


        <!-- Services -->
        <service
            android:name=".providers.audio.player.player.PlaybackService"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge"/>
        <service android:exported="false" tools:node="merge" android:name=".providers.radio.player.RadioService" />
        <service android:exported="false" tools:node="merge" android:name=".attachmentviewer.MusicService" />

        <!--
        A receiver that will receive media buttons and send as
        intents to your MediaBrowserServiceCompat implementation.
        Required on pre-Lollipop. More information at
        http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html
        -->
        <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="false" tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".providers.audio.player.media.MediaSessionReceiver"
            android:exported="false" tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--<receiver android:name=".providers.soundcloud.player.player.PlayerReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->

        <!-- Meta Data -->
        <meta-data

            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false" tools:node="merge"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="remove"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

`

I am tryin edit my app on playstore consol but i am getting the following error
You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

even thouhg i have exported android

Comment: The answer lies in your question itself. If you have read the error properly then it says activity with intent filters, service, providers or receivers should have exported set to true. Secondly, you do not need to specify exported=false in each and every tag inside manifest

Comment: You are using library which adds own app component which has no such attribute ... prolly there is newer version of the library or you have to use diferent one